# Running an Apple Script at desired location

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to make an Apple Scrip that builds me a project and runs it. To build the project, I need to run the python3 file at the repo's root. The steps I'm trying to replicate with my script are:

1. Open a dialogue, asking if the project wants to be built or not
2. If it wants to be built, open the terminal window
3. Once the terminal window is open, travel to the repo's folder
4. Once at the repo's, run the python3 script ***exactly there***

The result I'm getting, instead, is that the AppleScript is opening two terminals: one travels to the desired location, and the other one runs the python3 file at my computer's root (which is ~ I believe). With that, the python3 script can't reach the desired files to build the project (all located at the repo's root).

Is there a way to solve this or I'm expecting too much of an AppleScript?

This is my script:

```
to run
    set dialogText to "Do you want to build Effekseer first?"
    display dialog dialogText buttons {"Skip", "Yes"} default button "Skip"
    
    if result = {button returned:"Yes"} then
        tell application "Terminal"
            if not (exists window 1) then reopen
            activate
            do script "cd ~/Documents/_Repos/Effekseer"
            do shell script "python3 ~/Documents/_Repos/Effekseer/build.py"
        end tell
        
        set isBusy to true
        repeat until isBusy is false
            tell application "Terminal"
                tell window 1
                    set isBusy to busy as boolean
                end tell
            end tell
            delay 1
        end repeat
        do shell script "~/Documents/_Repos/Effekseer/Dev/Release/Effekseer"
        
    else if result = {button returned:"Skip"} then
        do shell script "~/Documents/_Repos/Effekseer/Dev/Release/Effekseer"
    end if
end run
```

Thank you so much for your help guys!

Comment: "my computer's root (which is ~ I believe)" You believe wrong. Your computer's root is `/`. The tilde `~` is your user home.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `cd` and your `python3` are in *two different shell sessions* so the `cd` has no effect on where the python script runs. Combine them into *one* shell script.

```
do shell script "cd ~/Documents/_Repos/Effekseer; python3 ~/Documents/_Repos/Effekseer/build.py"
```

Comment: For details on running shell scripts within applescript, take a look at [TN2065](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2065/_index.html).

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that your cd and your python3 are in 2 different shell sessions so the cd has no effect on where the python script runs. Combine them into **single do script command**.

Also, to avoid additional windows creation, you should **do script in window 1**.

To control the status of the project build process, the easiest way to do this is with the **busy property** of the Terminal window. What you are doing.

```
to run
    
    set dialogText to "Do you want to build Effekseer first?"
    display dialog dialogText buttons {"Skip", "Yes"} default button "Skip"
    
    if result = {button returned:"Yes"} then
        
        tell application "Terminal"
            if not (exists window 1) then reopen
            activate
            do script "cd ~/Documents/_Repos/Effekseer; python3 ~/Documents/_Repos/Effekseer/build.py" in window 1
            tell window 1 to repeat while busy
                delay 1
            end repeat
        end tell
        
    end if
    do shell script "~/Documents/_Repos/Effekseer/Dev/Release/Effekseer"
    
end run
```